# How to enable C11 and -Wall in Qt Creator? I use qbs to create the project

Tags: c, qt, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator 5.8(Windows version) to make C project, and I choose qbs to config the project.
I want the following things to be implemented while compiling:

1. Use C11 standard for my C project
2. Use -Wall to get highest warning level
3. Visual Studio has unsafe waring, it's a great feature, For example, if you use strcpy, it'll warn you and suggest to use strcpy_s. I want to if I can set up such unsafe warning in Qt Creator?

I checked on website how to config .qbs file, but still not quite clear about it. The following shows the .qbs file I use:

```
import qbs

CppApplication {
    consoleApplication: true
    files: "main.c"
    Depends {name: "c"}
    c.warningLevel: 'all'
    c.cLanguageVersion: "c11"

    Group {     // Properties for the produced executable
        fileTagsFilter: product.type
        qbs.install: true
    }
}
```